# How to change portal expiry error message text in DotNetNuke 4?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is there some way we can customize a Child Portal Expiry message text in DNN 4?

Right now it displays something like:

> The hosting contract for **XYZ Firm** expired on **DATE**. Please contact
>   **EMAIL** for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Admin>Languages> click the pencil next to site. Click the + next to global resources. Click on shared resources. Click the CTRL key and the F key and paste this Resource Name: ContractExpired.Error then click on the pencil next to it and edit at will.... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Language Editor (Admin, Languages) to alter the text.

Are the name, date, and email being filled in correctly?

Comment: Yes, the values actually are coming up correctly, but I would like to change the message text altogether without displaying any email address.

Comment: Use the language editor to locate and find the text and edit it there.